# Very Huge Sized Cache of Duplicity

Tags: linux, centos, backup, duplicity

I am currently using a duplicity script to backup my 110G/2T CentOS server to a 2T sftp server.

Since 4 days passed, duplicity backed up just 90G. This is not a problem. The main problem is; I have got nearly 600G cache that duplicity generated at "/user/.cache/duplicity". This size is not normal, so what should I do? Will duplicity shrink or remove these cache files and folders when finished the task? Will duplicity backup it's cache too (I did not exclude the /user folder)?

Additional info:
I am using Hetzner server and this is the backup script that I am using:
https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Duplicity_Script/en

In addition, I just excluded directories proc, sys and dev from the root (and backed up everything else starting from the root, because I wanted a full server backup).

Comment: I have seen this before. I have never seen a solution before. But the cache is safe to delete, as long as duplicity is not running.

Comment: Local cache is safe to delete. But will re-download, as far as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/duplicity-talk/2010-02/msg00006.html)

> you will have to manually exclude it ..
>
> it holds your backup chains index files (table of contents of the
>   backup repository). Caching them locally accelerates options like
>   status and incremental backup and others. These operations need to
>   know what is already backed up to work. If they are cached they do not
>   need to be transferred and decrypted every time again and again.
>
> .. ede

For the rest it seems to be a [long standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/706885).

On the Debian bug tracker, [they recommend to](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=572792)

```
duplicity cleanup --extra-clean --force ....
```

**Warning**: The suggested `--extra-clean` option is dangerous and can bite you very hard. It makes backups [unrestorable by usual means](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=724594).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so I must exclude those folders.
What I must ask now is this command that you gave me "duplicity cleanup --extra-clean --force ....". Must I use this after the backup process ends or every time that I need?

Comment: About that recommendation: You should be VERY sure about handling backups older than the current active backup chain (1 week?). Before PURGING metadata with --extra-clean. You will need that old metadata for the restore of old backups.

Answer (score 1):

Better to set the proper parameters in your config file to control the validity of your backup and the purge it:

```
# Time frame for old backups to keep, Used for the "purge" command.
# see duplicity man page, chapter TIME_FORMATS)
MAX_AGE=6M

# Number of full backups to keep. Used for the "purge-full" command.
# See duplicity man page, action "remove-all-but-n-full".
MAX_FULL_BACKUPS=2

# Number of full backups for which incrementals will be kept for.
# Used for the "purge-incr" command.
# See duplicity man page, action "remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full".
MAX_FULLS_WITH_INCRS=2

# activates duplicity --full-if-older-than option (since duplicity v0.4.4.RC3)
# forces a full backup if last full backup reaches a specified age, for the
# format of MAX_FULLBKP_AGE see duplicity man page, chapter TIME_FORMATS
# Uncomment the following two lines to enable this setting.
MAX_FULLBKP_AGE=2M
```

And then run the purge commands to see what would be deleted and then rerun it with the --force option to delete them:

```
duply your_config  purgeFull --force
Start duply v2.2, time is 2023-08-05 23:52:50.


--- Start running command PURGEFULL at 23:52:50.544 ---
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Fri Jul 21 18:13:20 2023
Deleting backup chains at times:
Sun Feb 26 10:32:51 2023
Sun Mar 19 08:07:44 2023
Mon Apr 17 13:46:08 2023
Fri May 19 16:40:16 2023
Sat Jun 10 09:24:03 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sat Jun 10 09:24:03 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sat Jun 10 09:24:03 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Fri May 19 16:40:16 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Fri May 19 16:40:16 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Mon Apr 17 13:46:08 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Mon Apr 17 13:46:08 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sun Mar 19 08:07:44 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sun Mar 19 08:07:44 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sun Feb 26 10:32:51 2023
Deleting complete signature chain Sun Feb 26 10:32:51 2023
Deleting complete backup chain Sat Jun 10 09:24:03 2023
Deleting complete backup chain Fri May 19 16:40:16 2023
Deleting complete backup chain Mon Apr 17 13:46:08 2023
Deleting complete backup chain Sun Mar 19 08:07:44 2023
Deleting complete backup chain Sun Feb 26 10:32:51 2023
--- Finished state OK at 23:52:57.431 - Runtime 00:00:06.887 ---
```

If you put this is a monthly cron the cleanup will happen accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When we started cleaning up very old backups remotely (S3), then duply commands started to delete very old local metadata automatically.

That is, we are keeping backups for only x months now. And the local metadata cache size did shrink accordingly.